# Get immediate class name jquery

Tags: jquery, xhtml

The html is

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Onhover class **'b'** I would like to get the classname **'a'** via jquery.

Is it possible.Please suggest.Much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear.. but try this `$(this).prev()[0].className`

Comment: I did not get it. On Hover action, you want to get the classname of the previous element ?

Comment: Sorry if the question is not clear.Thanks for your advice.It works.

Comment: the ques is edited now...let me know please if it is unclear.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.b').on('mouseover',function(){
    alert($(this).prev()[0].className);
});
```

Comment: I always equate jQuery `mouseenter` with `:hover`, `mouseover` is just too much.

Comment: @Vega  Could you elaborate your comment? Seems interesting but unfortunately, i don't understand it.

Comment: CSS `:hover` = jQuery `mouseenter`. What am trying to say is, it is better to use `mouseenter` instead of `mousemove`.

Comment: @Vega "CSS :hover = jQuery mouseenter" I don't think so. "CSS :hover = jQuery mouseenter + jQuery mouseleave  seems more accurate

Comment: @roasted True, my point was on using the `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do something like that :

var className = $('.a').attr('class');

EDIT: "ok onhover"..

Answer (score 0):

If there are only these two divs, you can use following code :

```
 jQuery('.b').hover(function(){
    var x = jQuery('div[class!="b"]').attr('class');
    console.log(x);
 });
```

Here is working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/n5Nnf/

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/42/

```
<div class="a" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red;"></div>
<div class="b" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:green;"></div>

  $("div.b").mouseover(function() {
    alert($(this).prev('div').attr('class'))
  });
```